# Does adding or deleting columns to a table force recreation of all indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, indexing

Specifically in MySQL (though I would assume that the same would hold true for Oracle, and Microsoft SQL Server ). If I add or delete a column to a table, will all the current indexes (on that table) need to be created from scratch?

I would imagine that if we are changing table row size (by adding/deleting columns) then the ROWIDS will change (non clustered table), consequently forcing the recreation of all indexes.

If a clustered index is used (Index Organized Table in Oracle), then I would imagine that the entire clustered index would have to be recreated as well.

If all indexes need to be recreated, are there any strategies to optimize the rebuild time?

Comment: the rowid should not change.  you may get undesired chaining effects.

Comment: In SQL Server it will only recreate indexes that refer to that column.  The clustered index will change but the clustered index is really the table, not just an index.

Comment: That being said it will still be messy because it will lead to page splits and pointers and all sorts of nasty storage-level issues.

Comment: Since posting an answer would be too long, you can refer to [MySQL ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) manual page to see what happens since it's described in detail. I know that TokuDB MySQL engine supports hot scheme changes that don't rebuild the index from the scratch.

Comment: @NB - unless I missed something the link you provided doesn't provide a clear answer to my question ... though it does recommend increasing the myisam_sort_buffer_size system variable to a high value to speed up index recreation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say what version of MySQL and which storage engine. But I suspect the answer to your question is on this page:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

The short answer to your question is Yes, the entire table will be rebuilt (all data and all indexes) when you add or delete a column. To improve the speed, try the following:

MyISAM:
Increase the value of myisam_sort_buffer_size

InnoDB:
Increase innodb_buffer_pool_size

Increase innodb_log_file_size

Either storage engine:
Use the smallest column data types possible for your columns.

Source: I'm a Certified MySQL DBA.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to reply. Searching Google for "innodb_buffer_pool_size" will give a plethora of good answers, but the summary of them all is generally:
For a dedicated MySQL server that is 100% InnoDb, you would probably want to use at LEAST 75% of your physical RAM as your InnoDB buffer pool. Make sure your OS has enough memory first, though.